# dynamic indexing using labels in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to dynamically index elements of a pandas DataFrame using labels.
Say I have

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 4),
                   index=list('abcdef'),
                   columns=list('ABCD'))
```

and I want the element with labels 'a' and 'A'.

"Statically" it's easy:

```
df1.loc['a','A']
```

But how to do build such a query dynamically at runtime?

```
indexer = ['a', 'A']
df1.loc[indexer]   .... fails!
```

I don't understand the internals of loc, and what kind of an object it receives/accepts...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [numpy indexing documentation with variable number of indices](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#dealing-with-variable-numbers-of-indices-within-programs), it's possible to use a tuple (but not a list) for what I want to do:

```
In[141]: indexer = ('a', 'A')
In[142]: df1.loc[indexer]
Out[141]: -0.25517278351855893
```

Answer (score 1):

try this instead

```
df1.loc[indexer[0], indexer[1]]
```

Comment: I actually also have a variable number of indices so this doesn't help.